# Bootrstrap 4 modal in Chrome extenstion

Tags: google-chrome-extension, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

My Chrome extenstion consists of the following files:

- manifest.json
- background.js
- content.js

background.js sends a message to content.js when the browser action is clicked. That's when I want to show the modal, which is going to show data from the messeage.

**Where do I store the HTML (the hidden modal) and how do I access it?**

---

**UPDATE**

I create an iframe in content.js like this:

```
var iframe = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));
iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL('modal.html');
```

**modal.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
     </head>

     <body>

         <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
             <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header">
                         <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                         </button>
                     </div>
                     <div class="modal-body">
                         ...
                     </div>
                     <div class="modal-footer">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>

         <script src="jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
         <script src="popper.min.js"></script>
         <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Anslutningsstatus Webbtidbokning",
    "description": "Visar vilka webbtidbokningsflöden i 1177 Vårdguidens e-tjänster som en vårdenhet har stöd för baserat på vilka tjänstekontrakt den är ansluten till.",
    "version": "0.1",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["browser-polyfill.min.js", "background.js", "axios.min.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon16.png"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": ["content.js", "styles.css", "modal.html"]

}
```

What happens is that a 300 px wide, totally blank iframe is injected into the page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The most clean approach is to add an iframe DOM element in your content script with src pointing to chrome.runtime.getURL('your-modal.html'). That html page should be declared in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources), and can contain anything you want - it's just an extension page. You can find existing answers, complete tutorials, and demos for this approach.

Comment: Thanks (again)! How do I give this HTML page access to data that was sent from background.js to content.js?

Comment: [Open a port](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) to your bg page in that iframe script directly so they can talk. If you need some data from the content script, the most secure approach is to send from the content to bg, then bg sends to the iframe's port. If this sounds too complicated, you can use ShadowDOM to append html directly to the web page in your content script, look for complete tutorials on doing that.

Comment: Cool! I'll do that. Do I really need to save the Boostrap .js and .css files to my extension folder? If so, should I just reference them in a script-tag in my HTML page?

Comment: Yes, packaging all dependencies within the extension is faster, more reliable, and more secure.

Comment: Please have a look at my update.

Comment: You didn't show manifest.json so I guess you either didn't declare web_accessible_resources correctly or you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page, or didn't reload the web page.

Comment: BTW regarding the communication, your iframe can use chrome.tabs.getCurrent (to get its own tab id) + chrome.**tabs**.connect to open a port directly to your content script in that tab.

Comment: I have added manifest.json to the description. What's acually *supposed* to happen when I inject the iframe? Is the modal supposed to pop up like usual?

Comment: An iframe is a separate page. It's a separate document, separate DOM, separate everything. So you need a separate script there too. BTW no need to make content.js web-accessible, only the iframe stuff goes there.

Comment: content.js was declared in web-accessible from before but I removed it now.

From my understanding I'm injecting a whole HTML page called modal.html into an existing one (the page I'm visiting). It makes sense to me that the page I'm visiting gets messed up. I don't get it. What is *supposed* to happen? What's the expected result from me appendening modal.html to the page I'm visiting?

Comment: Like I said, an iframe is a different document, its inner contents is not part of the page.

Comment: I am aware that an ifram is a different document. I added $('#exampleModal').modal('show'); to modal.html and the modal is now being shown. The problem is that it's being shown within that little 300 px element of the page I'm visiting. I must do something wrong?

Comment: Well simply set CSS in the `style` attribute on the iframe element itself in your content.js

Comment: Oh, now I might get the implications of the fact that the iframe is different document. I can't make the modal appear like a modal is supposed to: **on top** of the page I'm visiting but with the page I'm visiting still visible in the background. Right?

Comment: You can. Simply use the appropriate CSS like position: absolute or fixed. I won't be following this thread anymore since these questions are separate.